# Retrieve blob storage connection string using az cli or python sdk?

Tags: python, azure, connection-string

Is there a python function to retrieve a blob storage account connection string?

- If so, how is this accomplished?
- If not, is there a way to retrieve a SAS token using `az cli` or `python`?

Thank you

Comment: What version of Python SDK you're using? Can you share some code that you have written and tell us what's the issue you're running into.

Comment: I'm using `notebooks.azure.com`. I can't find a way to determine the SDK version. Regarding code, I've looked through all the samples mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-python/storage-blob-samples/. They all BEGIN with the connection string. I want to programmatically get it, not visit the azure portal gui. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If using CLI is an option, you can get connection string for a storage account by using [`az storage account show-connection-string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-show-connection-string) command.

```
az storage account show-connection-string --name MyStorageAccount --resource-group MyResourceGroup --subscription MySubscription
```

To get Shared Access Signature for a blob, you can use [`az storage blob generate-sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-generate-sas) command.

```
end=`date -u -d "30 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ'`
az storage blob generate-sas -c myycontainer -n MyBlob --permissions r --expiry $end --https-only
```

Comment: Thank you. My search criteria was wrong. `get connection string azure blob storage python sdk` yields no relevant results where `get connection string azure blob storage azure cli` lead me to the resources you suggest. Thank you!

Comment: Just found another method using [Azure Functions Core Tools][1]: `func azure storage fetch-connection-string <StorageAccountName>`. In case this is useful to someone.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=linux%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#get-your-storage-connection-strings